# Wordpress custom front-page.php file not loading functions.php

Tags: wordpress

I am creating a custom wordpress front-page.php script.  It is the only thing I have customized so far. I need Bootstrap, Google Icons, and jquery to make things look good and responsive. I have enqueued all the need scripts and css in the functions.php file. When I look at the dev-tools network tab I see that none of the functions.php actions have loaded on the front-page.php when I run it.  If I click on a link on the front page to a post or page, which have not been styled they are wordpress default, when the default post or page loads so do all of my enqueued items in the functions file.

So, my question is why doesn't the front page load the functions.php file?  Is there some sort of statement I need to put in the code on that page?  Do I need to tell wordpress to use functions.php on a custom front-page.php?

When I manually put the scripts and links in the head of my front-page.php file it works beautifully and all the links to pages and post work great.

Oh, there are no plugins, or server cache, or anything.  It is a clean install of wordpress on a local machine running in XAMPP.

Any ideas would be helpful. Thank you in advance.

Here is what I have done so far without success:

Check Your Theme Files:

Ensure that your custom front-page.php file is located in the correct theme folder (usually within the "themes" directory).
Verify that there are no syntax errors or typos in your front-page.php file that could be causing issues.
Verify WordPress Template Hierarchy:

Make sure that your front-page.php is set up correctly according to the WordPress template hierarchy. It should serve as the template for your site's front page.
jQuery Enqueue:

While you've enqueued jQuery and jQuery Migrate in your functions.php file, make sure there are no conflicts with other scripts or plugins that might be preventing jQuery from loading on your front page.
Check the browser's developer console for any JavaScript errors or conflicts that might be blocking jQuery.
Bootstrap Enqueue:

Ensure that Bootstrap is correctly enqueued in your functions.php file and that there are no errors or conflicts related to Bootstrap.
Verify that the Bootstrap version you are enqueuing is compatible with your WordPress version.
Theme or Plugin Conflicts:

Disable all plugins temporarily to see if any of them are causing the issue. Sometimes, conflicts with plugins can lead to unexpected behavior.
Try switching to a default WordPress theme (e.g., Twenty Twenty-One) to see if Bootstrap and jQuery load correctly on the front page. If they do, the issue might be related to your theme.
Caching:

Clear any caching plugins or server-side caching that might interfere with script loading.
jQuery Usage:

Ensure that your front-page.js file doesn't use jQuery before it's loaded. You should place any jQuery-dependent code inside a document ready function or use jQuery's noConflict mode.
Theme Documentation:

Check if your theme has specific documentation or recommendations for enqueueing scripts. Some themes have unique requirements for adding scripts.
Server Configuration:

Verify that your server configuration doesn't have any restrictions on script loading.
Console Log:

Add a console.log statement at the beginning of your front-page.js file to check if it's loading correctly when you visit the front page. If you see this log in your browser's console, it means your JavaScript file is being loaded.
Review WordPress Settings:

Check your WordPress settings, including reading settings and front page settings, to ensure they are configured correctly.
Browser Extensions:

Disable browser extensions or try accessing your site using a different web browser to rule out any browser-related issues.

Answer (score 0):

To include Bootstrap, Google Icons, and jQuery in your custom WordPress front-page.php file, you can enqueue these scripts and styles in your theme's functions.php file.

Make sure your `front-page.php` file is structured with a call to `get_header()` at the beginning and `get_footer()` at the end.

By using these code snippets, you should have Bootstrap, Google Icons, and jQuery properly enqueued in your WordPress theme, specifically on the front page. Adjust URLs and versions as needed for your project.